# How to add a line to a file which has only root write permission and to continue the script execution

Tags: bash, scripting, io-redirection, root

I am trying to learn bash scripting. I am working on a practical problem and at one point I need to add a line to a file which requires `root` permission to write.

The code looks like this:

```
# some code
echo "add this line to the code" >> fileName
# some code
```

Is it possible to somehow make the script ask for the root password, validate the password, and on successful authentication modify the file? The script should then return to the user mode and continue the command execution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a tip in the `sudo` man page which explains how to do something like this. Here's my one-liner:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
sudo sh -c "echo \"add this line to the code\" >> fileName"
```

Obviously, you'll first have to set up your user to have `sudo` privileges. The `sh` shell is used because of the redirection to the root-owned file. I also had to escape the quotes used for the `echo` command.

Answer (score 2):

`su` is available on most unix systems and should work:

```
su root -c 'echo "add this line to the code" >> fileName'
```

Comment: Unlike with `sudo`, passwords don't seem to get cached with `su`.

Comment: @Ryne Everett: I am not familiar with sudo.  But the behaviour of 'su' is actually as needed by the script of the OP. Most of the time I use 'su' the other way round: changing from root to another user. In this case no password is needed ast all.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tee` with `sudo`:

```
echo "add this line to the code" | sudo tee -a filename > /dev/null
```

`echo`'s output is redirected with `|` (*pipe*) to `sudo tee`.
`tee` reads from *standard input* and writes to *standard output* any given file, in this case `filename`. `-a` (or `--append`) makes `tee` append to files, without it the files would be overwritten. 
As `tee` is run with `sudo` it opens files with root-permissions. Finally, `> /dev/null` suppresses `tee`'s output to *standard output*.

One advantage of using `tee` instead of just starting the whole command including redirection with `su -c` or `sudo sh -c` is, that you do not have to change the quoting of the initial command in any way (Quoting lines already containing quotes can get quite ugly at times).

Answer (score 0):

Try this
This command is available on Unix and Linux.

`sudo sh -c "echo 'add this line to the code' >> fileName"`

Answer (score -2):

Would do the trick:

```
ssh host "sudo su root -c 'echo "add this line to the code" >> /etc/hosts'"
```

Comment: Why `ssh`? You do not need `su` with `sudo` and neither do you need to specify `root` as it is the default. All in all, a bit more explanations would be nice as the OP wanted to learn something and not just a problem solved.

Comment: I think you will run into troubles  with you double quotes